# If $T:X \rightarrow Y$ is a linear operator and $r>0$ such that $r \cdot B_Y \subseteq T(B_X)$, show $y ||x|| \leq M ||y||$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces and let $B_X$ and $B_Y$ denote the closed unit balls in $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Suppose $T:X \rightarrow Y$ is a linear operator and that there is an $r>0$ such that $r \cdot B_Y  \subseteq T(B_X)$.

Show that for any $y \in Y$, there is an $x \in X$ such that $y=Tx$ and $\|x\| \leq M \|y\|$ where M is a constant independent of Y.

After having written out definitions, I'm stuck on how to proceed and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Given $y \in Y$, we have

$$y = \left( r\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right) \cdot \frac{\|y\|}{r}$$

This should also show how to select the $M$ in terms of $r$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y\in Y$. Then $\|\frac{y}{\|y\|}\| = 1$ and therefore $\frac{y}{\|y\|}\in B_Y\subset \frac{1}{r}T(B_X)$. So there exists $x_0\in B_X$ such that $\frac{1}{r}T(x_0) = \frac{y}{\|y\|}$ and therefore $y = T(\frac{1}{r}\|y\|x_0)$. Let $x = \frac{1}{r}\|y\|x_0$. Now, we have $y=T(x)$ and since $\|x_0\|\leq 1$ we have
$$\frac{\|x\|}{\|y\|} = \frac{\|y\|\|x_0\| |\frac{1}{r}|}{\|y\|} = \frac{\|x_0\|\frac{1}{r}}{1}\leq \frac{1}{r}$$

So, you may set $M =\frac{1}{r}$